# In PowerApps, is there any way to add "show all records" option in radio button filters?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-modeldriven, powerapps-selected-items

I have created a PowerApp using the "Projects" SharePoint list as the data source. I have successfully applied multiple filters on gallery items. I have applied radion buttons with choices "Pending", "Approved", "Rejected" to filter the records based on the selected choice. But I am unable to add the "Show all" option to show all the records in the gallery.
If you have worked on any similar case, please share your experience.
Your valuable suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: The show all can be achieved by having a switch or if on your filter. Basically if ShowAll is selected filter where 1=1, else filter with your selected radio

Answer (score 1):

I got similar requirements and my solution is

1. Create 2 Radio controls (A and B)
2. For Radio A, set Items to ["Show all"]
3. For Radio B, set Items to your normal choices e.g. ["Pending", "Approved", "Rejected"]
4. Set OnSelect of RadioA to Reset(RadioB)
5. Set OnSelect of RadioB to Reset(RadioA)
6. Put 2 controls close to make them look like from one Radio control